# Check certain number of days using date in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

i am new in SQL and need help by a task which we got from school.
The following task is:

**Who has exceeded the permissible borrowing period of 2 weeks**

I have already written that code.

```
select borrow.user_id from borrow where count(return_date - borrow_date) > 14;
```

I am not really sure what I am doing there. I know that its wrong but yea... I don't really know how to do it.

I hope someone understands my problem and can help...
Thanks for your advice

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and explain why your code does not work.

Comment: Take a look in the manual under Date and Time Functions

Comment: Not just date and time functions, you can't use `count` like that

Comment: read up on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff and consider what should happen if return data is null. Also I hope you are storing dates as date datatypes.

Comment: OK. Yea the output should be a table where all users which Borrowing period  over two weeks... 

like that

user_id | days over the date
0           | 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need `datediff` as follows:

```
select borrow.user_id, 
       datediff(return_date, borrow_date) - interval 14 day as over_days 
  from borrow where datediff(return_date, borrow_date) > 14;
```

Comment: I'm confused. Who's taking this lesson?

Comment: Consider coalesce(ing) dates.

Comment: Coalesce is not needed I think. as null dates will not be passed through the condition and I guess it is not needed in the result also.

Comment: It's overdue if there is no return date surely?

Comment: Let OP give some comment on it @P.Salmon :P

Comment: yea if some borrowed books are overdue there should be a return of the user_id and the borrowed book id

Comment: yeap that is the solution for my problem... Thanks guys and have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Use `datediff` instead of directly subtracting 2 dates

```
SELECT borrow.user_id
FROM borrow
WHERE DATEDIFF(return_date, borrow_date) > 14;
```

Check documentation of [datediff](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_datediff.asp)